# dropwizard service kerberos authentication to hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, microservices, kerberos, dropwizard

I have a working microservice (dropwizard) code that communicates to the kerberozied Hadoop cluster using a keytab file in my local environment. Since keytab contains user and password information, I couldn't check-in into the project. I was told to save the keytab data into some secure storage (like vault) and create the keytab file by reading the data from the secure storage inside the service. I am looking for some help to my below questions:

1. Best practices to pass a keytab file to the service in production.
2. How to create a file (keytab) inside a service? I certainly understand writing files using java file system API but I'm checking whether there are any popular libraries that support this feature.

Comment: A "vault" is typically used by automation software (e.g. Ansible, Kubernetes) that **deploys** the service, not by the service itself. From a _Dev_ point of view, your code should assume that the keytab file is present under a specific path and with appropriate access privs. It's _Ops_ job to deploy the keytab -- and possibly update it whenever password rotation is mandated.

Comment: For the record, a keytab file is either managed by a KDC admin tool (e.g. `ktpass.exe` for Microsoft Active Directory, `ipa-getkeytab` for FreeIPA, etc) or created/updated manually with `ktutil` (on Linux)